# Can the Kong TCP type plug-in only work globally but not locally?

Tags: nginx, kong, openresty, kong-plugin, konga

I have a `Kong` TCP plugin, I use this for user validation. I find it can only work in global, but I want it to work only on some `routers`. When I add it to `routers` or `services`, it does not work. My steps are as follows
1 add the plugin with `handler.lua` and `schema.lua`
2 the `handler.lua` is like this

```
function MyAuthHandler:preread(conf)
    ...parsing header
end
return MyAuthHandler
```

3 I add `plugin` through web like `konga`, if I add the plugin as global, it works. But it does not work if I add the plugin to some `routers`

My question is： Is there any special setting required for locally effective plugins? Or is there some doc?